# Captured image using custom camera is in wrong orientation

Tags: android, image, camera

I am created custom camera activity But captured  image is in wrong orientation. when i am capturing image in portrait mode  and after rotating it 90 degree.it is in original position but Capturing image in wrong orientation in landscape mode.

Camera Orientation While capture image in Landscape.
[image]

Resulted Image
[image]

Camera orientation While capturing image in Portrait mode

[image]

Resulted image [image]

For resolve camera preview problem.

```
public int setPhotoOrientation(Activity activity, int cameraId) {
        android.hardware.Camera.CameraInfo info = new android.hardware.Camera.CameraInfo();
        android.hardware.Camera.getCameraInfo(cameraId, info);
        int rotation = activity.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getRotation();
        int degrees = 0;
        switch (rotation) {
            case Surface.ROTATION_0:
                degrees = 0;
                break;
            case Surface.ROTATION_90:
                degrees = 90;
                break;
            case Surface.ROTATION_180:
                degrees = 180;
                break;
            case Surface.ROTATION_270:
                degrees = 270;
                break;
        }

        int result;
        // do something for phones running an SDK before lollipop
        if (info.facing == Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT) {
            result = (info.orientation + degrees) % 360;
            result = (360 - result) % 360; // compensate the mirror
        } else { // back-facing
            result = (info.orientation - degrees + 360) % 360;
        }

        return result;
    }
```

Check bitmap orientation.

```
private Bitmap imageOreintationValidator(Bitmap bitmap, String path) {

        ExifInterface ei;
        try {
            ei = new ExifInterface(path);
            int orientation = ei.getAttributeInt(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION,
                    ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_NORMAL);
            switch (orientation) {
            case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_90:
                bitmap = rotateImage(bitmap, 90);
                rot++;
                break;
            case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_180:
                bitmap = rotateImage(bitmap, 180);
                rot++;
                break;
            case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_270:
                bitmap = rotateImage(bitmap, 270);
                rot++;
                break;
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return bitmap;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally Found Solution.Check orientation using orientation sensor and find angle according to angle and rotate resulted image using that angle.

```
public abstract class SimpleOrientationListener extends OrientationEventListener {

    public static final int CONFIGURATION_ORIENTATION_UNDEFINED = Configuration.ORIENTATION_UNDEFINED;
    private volatile int defaultScreenOrientation = CONFIGURATION_ORIENTATION_UNDEFINED;
    public int prevOrientation = OrientationEventListener.ORIENTATION_UNKNOWN;
    private Context ctx;
    private ReentrantLock lock = new ReentrantLock(true);

    public SimpleOrientationListener(Context context) {
        super(context);
        ctx = context;
    }

    public SimpleOrientationListener(Context context, int rate) {
        super(context, rate);
        ctx = context;
    }

    @Override
    public void onOrientationChanged(final int orientation) {


        int currentOrientation = OrientationEventListener.ORIENTATION_UNKNOWN;
        int angle=0;
        if (orientation >= 330 || orientation < 30) {
            currentOrientation = Surface.ROTATION_0;
            angle=90;
        } else if (orientation >= 60 && orientation < 120) {
            currentOrientation = Surface.ROTATION_90;
            angle=180;
        } else if (orientation >= 150 && orientation < 210) {
            currentOrientation = Surface.ROTATION_180;
            angle=270;
        } else if (orientation >= 240 && orientation < 300) {
            currentOrientation = Surface.ROTATION_270;
            angle=360;
        }
        getset g = new getset();
        g.setK(angle);
        if (prevOrientation != currentOrientation && orientation != OrientationEventListener.ORIENTATION_UNKNOWN) {
            prevOrientation = currentOrientation;
            if (currentOrientation != OrientationEventListener.ORIENTATION_UNKNOWN)
                reportOrientationChanged(currentOrientation);
        }

    }

    private void reportOrientationChanged(final int currentOrientation) {

        int defaultOrientation = getDeviceDefaultOrientation();
        int orthogonalOrientation = defaultOrientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE ? Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT
                : Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE;

        int toReportOrientation;

        if (currentOrientation == Surface.ROTATION_0 || currentOrientation == Surface.ROTATION_180)
            toReportOrientation = defaultOrientation;
        else
            toReportOrientation = orthogonalOrientation;

        onSimpleOrientationChanged(toReportOrientation);
    }

    /**
     * Must determine what is default device orientation (some tablets can have default landscape). Must be initialized when device orientation is defined.
     *
     * @return value of {@link Configuration#ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE} or {@link Configuration#ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT}
     */
    private int getDeviceDefaultOrientation() {
        if (defaultScreenOrientation == CONFIGURATION_ORIENTATION_UNDEFINED) {
            lock.lock();
            defaultScreenOrientation = initDeviceDefaultOrientation(ctx);
            lock.unlock();
        }
        return defaultScreenOrientation;
    }

    /**
     * Provides device default orientation
     *
     * @return value of {@link Configuration#ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE} or {@link Configuration#ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT}
     */
    private int initDeviceDefaultOrientation(Context context) {

        WindowManager windowManager = (WindowManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
        Configuration config = context.getResources().getConfiguration();
        int rotation = windowManager.getDefaultDisplay().getRotation();

        boolean isLand = config.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE;
        boolean isDefaultAxis = rotation == Surface.ROTATION_0 || rotation == Surface.ROTATION_180;

        int result = CONFIGURATION_ORIENTATION_UNDEFINED;
        if ((isDefaultAxis && isLand) || (!isDefaultAxis && !isLand)) {
            result = Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE;
        } else {
            result = Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT;
        }
        return result;
    }

    /**
     * Fires when orientation changes from landscape to portrait and vice versa.
     *
     * @param orientation value of {@link Configuration#ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE} or {@link Configuration#ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT}
     */
    public abstract void onSimpleOrientationChanged(int orientation);

}
```

For set camera orientation for preview.

```
public static int setCameraDisplayOrientation(Activity activity, int cameraId, android.hardware.Camera camera) {
        android.hardware.Camera.CameraInfo info = new android.hardware.Camera.CameraInfo();
        android.hardware.Camera.getCameraInfo(cameraId, info);
        int rotation = activity.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getRotation();
        int degrees = 0;
        switch (rotation) {
            case Surface.ROTATION_0:
                degrees = 0;
                break;
            case Surface.ROTATION_90:
                degrees = 90;
                break;
            case Surface.ROTATION_180:
                degrees = 180;
                break;
            case Surface.ROTATION_270:
                degrees = 270;
                break;
        }

        int result;
        //int currentapiVersion = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
        // do something for phones running an SDK before lollipop
        if (info.facing == Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT) {
            result = (info.orientation + degrees) % 360;
            result = (360 - result) % 360; // compensate the mirror
        } else { // back-facing
            result = (info.orientation - degrees + 360) % 360;
        }

        return result;

    }
```